# Upgrade libseccomp to latest version in airgapped Centos 7 server

Tags: centos, docker, centos7

I was trying to install docker rpm's in airgapped Centos 7 server and encountered error saying that libseccomp >=2.3 required.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch (/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch)
           Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-102
           Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7_2.13.noarch (@tm-rhel-x86_64-server-7.2.eus)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.13
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el7.x86_64 (/containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch (/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch)
           Requires: selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-102
           Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7_2.13.noarch (@tm-rhel-x86_64-server-7.2.eus)
               selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.13
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el7.x86_64 (/containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: libseccomp
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64)
           Requires: libseccomp >= 2.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I downloaded the libseccomp source offline from https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp, transfer to the server and run the usual

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However I continue to receive error `libseccomp >=2.3 required` when trying to install docker rpm again. Are there additional steps after `sudo make install` libseccomp? Do I need to enable Linux module or library to activate the new libseccomp.

For reference, below is the output of sudo make install

```
TEST [libseccomp-2.4.4]$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for testadmin:
Making install in include
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 seccomp.h seccomp-syscalls.h '/usr/local/include'
Making install in src
Making install in .
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libseccomp.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libseccomp.so.2.4.4 /usr/local/lib/libseccomp.so.2.4.4
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libseccomp.so.2.4.4 libseccomp.so.2 || { rm -f libseccomp.so.2 && ln -s libseccomp.so.2.4.4 libseccomp.so.2; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libseccomp.so.2.4.4 libseccomp.so || { rm -f libseccomp.so && ln -s libseccomp.so.2.4.4 libseccomp.so; }; })libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libseccomp.lai /usr/local/lib/libseccomp.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libseccomp.a /usr/local/lib/libseccomp.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libseccomp.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libseccomp.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Making install in tools
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c scmp_sys_resolver '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/scmp_sys_resolver /usr/local/bin/scmp_sys_resolver
Making install in tests
Making install in doc
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 man/man1/scmp_sys_resolver.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 man/man3/seccomp_arch_add.3 man/man3/seccomp_arch_exist.3 man/man3/seccomp_arch_native.3 man/man3/seccomp_arch_remove.3 man/man3/seccomp_arch_resolve_name.3 man/man3/seccomp_attr_get.3 man/man3/seccomp_attr_set.3 man/man3/seccomp_export_bpf.3 man/man3/seccomp_export_pfc.3 man/man3/seccomp_init.3 man/man3/seccomp_load.3 man/man3/seccomp_merge.3 man/man3/seccomp_release.3 man/man3/seccomp_reset.3 man/man3/seccomp_rule_add.3 man/man3/seccomp_rule_add_array.3 man/man3/seccomp_rule_add_exact.3 man/man3/seccomp_rule_add_exact_array.3 man/man3/seccomp_syscall_priority.3 man/man3/seccomp_syscall_resolve_name.3 man/man3/seccomp_syscall_resolve_name_arch.3 man/man3/seccomp_syscall_resolve_name_rewrite.3 man/man3/seccomp_syscall_resolve_num_arch.3 man/man3/seccomp_version.3 man/man3/seccomp_api_get.3 man/man3/seccomp_api_set.3 '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libseccomp.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
```

**EDIT**

Currently, docker rpm's are downloaded from https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/

```
TEST [docker-rpm]$ ls
containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-cli-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: The package management does not know about what you install from source. You can of course force the rpms to be installed, but this problem shouldn't have been occured in the first place. Are you sure you are installing the correct docker packages for your CentOS?

Comment: CentOS 7 has a `libseccomp-2.3.1-4.el7` package. Since your server is offline I assume you downloaded the docker packages manually. You should only need to download and install that package as well.

Comment: CentOS? Is this really CentOS, or RHEL? You are using repos named RHEL and seem to have held the system back at 7.2.